# Circular dependency when injecting services in effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an Angular 6 service which encapsulate HTTP request :

```
@Injectable({providedIn: MyModule})
export class MyService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpService) { }

  public getData(): Observable<model.Data[]> {
    return this._http.get('/my-service');
  }
}
```

and an @ngrx effect :

```
@Injectable()
export class MyEffects { 

@Effect()
load$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$.pipe(
  ofType<fromActions.Load>(fromActions.ActionTypes.Load),
  mergeMap(action => {
    return this._myService.getData();
  }),
  map(data => {
    return new fromActions.LoadSuccess(data);
  })
);

constructor(
    private _actions$: Actions,
    private _myService: MyService
  ) {}
}
```

The effect is registered in the same module as the service, which produces a circular dependency : Module -> Effect -> Service -> Module.

What is the best way to inject services in effects ? Can I still use the `{providedIn: MyModule}` syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use Injector

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
_myService = injector.get(MyService);
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry. It doesn't fix the problem : the effects file still refers the service file. The problem is about the references between files, not the dependency injection.

Comment: Yeap, That might be something else if you cannot fix that for almost 3 years